# 8051 microcontroller interface a 4bit LCD

Tags: c, microcontroller, lcd

I am working on interfacing a 4bit LCD with 8051 micro-controller, but till now i'm unsuccessful. I got this sample code

```
/*
developed by S4silver
license type - open source
created on - 11/12/2014
modified on - 11/14/2014
modification details - refactored
developer - Frank Hust Jincson
contact mail id - silverembeddedsolutions@gmail.com
web link - http://s4silver.blogspot.in/p/programmers-colony.html
*/

#include<reg51.h>

//#include"delay1s.h"

void Init_LCD(void);
void cmd_LCD(char cmd);
void display_LCD(char );
void write_LCD(char );

#define LCD P0

sbit RS=P0^0;
sbit RW=P0^1;
sbit EN=P0^2;

void delay()
{
    int i;
    TMOD=0X01;

    for(i=0;i<=16;i++)
    {
        TR0=1;
        while(!TF0);
        TF0=0;
        TR0=0;
    }
}

main()
{
    Init_LCD();
    display_LCD('A');
}

void Init_LCD()
{
    cmd_LCD(0x28);
    cmd_LCD(0x0e);
    cmd_LCD(0x01);
    cmd_LCD(0x06);
    cmd_LCD(0x80);
}

void cmd_LCD(char cmd)
{
    LCD=(cmd&0xf0)|0x04; //0x20,en=1,rs=0
    delay();
    EN=0;
    LCD=(cmd<<4)|0x04;  //0x80,en=1,rs=0
    delay();
    EN=0;
}

void display_LCD(char c)
{
    LCD=(c&0xf0)|0x05; //en=1,rs=1
    delay();
    EN=0;
    LCD=(c<<4)|0x05; //en=1,rs=1
    delay();
    EN=0;
}
```

But it is not working for me and I don't know what is wrong with it.

Comment: This code, doesn't look good, `main()` has no return type, it should be `int` and what is `while(!TF0);` supposed to do?

Comment: I like the "license type - open source"

Comment: I don't work with 8051, but my AVR library file for interfacing HD44780 in 4-bit mode is here - maybe it'll help you. Your init routine in particular doesn't look correct, but might be that I'm wrong. Also, you are supposed to send a pulse on the EN, not sure you're doing that right. Try adding some delay. https://github.com/MightyPork/avr-projects/blob/master/devel/lib/lcd.h

Comment: thanks, i'll be looking into that

Comment: according to the 8051 compiler that I have, port bits are addressed via things like P0.1, not P0^1 which is more of an exclusive OR operation on the whole port.

Comment: there are several errors, here is one:  line:'cmd_LCD(0x28);' and in the cmd_LCD() function: 'LCD=(cmd&0xf0)|0x04; //0x20,en=1,rs=0' results in 0x20 | 0x04 results in 0x24.  Obviously not what is wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following code that is in C language

```
#include<reg51.h>
#define lcdport P2
sbit rs=P3^0;
sbit rw=P3^1;
sbit en=P3^2;
void lcdcmd(char);
void lcdint();
void lcddata(char);
void lcdstring(char *);
void delay(unsigned int);

void main()
{
lcdport=0x00;               // output port
 while(1)
  {
   lcdint();
   delay(500);
   lcdstring("hello welcome to");
   lcdcmd(0xc0);
   delay(500000);
   lcdstring("projectguru.net");
   delay(500000);
   }
}         
void delay(unsigned int x)
{
 unsigned int i;
 for(i=0;i<x;i++);
}
void lcdint()               // lcd initializing
{
  lcdcmd(0x38);
  delay(500);
  lcdcmd(0x01);
  delay(500);
  lcdcmd(0x0c);
  delay(500);
  lcdcmd(0x80);
  delay(500);
  lcdcmd(0x0e);
  delay(500);
}
void lcdcmd(char value)        //  lcd command
{
  lcdport = value;
  rw=0;
  rs=0;
  en=1;
  delay(500);
  en=0;
}
void lcdstring(char *p)      
{
  while(*p!='\0')
   {
     lcddata(*p);
     delay(2000);
     p++;
   }
}
void lcddata(char value)   // print data on lcd
{
  lcdport = value;
  rs=1;
  rw=0;
  en=1; 
  delay(500);
  en=0;
}
```

A complete tutorial along with video is give here http://www.mechaterrain.com/lcd-interfacing-8051